# Limit items per page in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

What is the best way to limit the items per page in Django REST Framework? I set PAGINATE_BY = 20 and PAGINATE_BY_PARAM. Without parameter you get 20 items but it is also possible to get 4000 items over the paginate param. This requests are very heavy and not very useful but perfect for script kiddies.

Jarus

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to set a hard maximum limit look at overriding the `get_paginate_by` method on the generic views.

Comment: You're welcome to submit a pull request for a MAX_PAGINATE_BY setting.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set `PAGINATE_BY` as [doc](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings.html) states:

> **PAGINATE_BY**: The default page size to use for pagination. If set to
>   None, pagination is disabled by default

`PAGINATE_BY_PARAM` is for users to override the default size. So if you are afraid of its misuse just don't enable it.

> **PAGINATE_BY_PARAM**: The name of a query parameter, which can be used by
>   the client to override the default page size to use for pagination. If
>   set to None, clients may not override the default page size.

Comment: Note that `PAGINATE_BY` and `PAGINATE_BY_PARAM` are now pending depreciation: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/

Answer (score 3):

Better to go through [Pagination](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/)

The `PageNumberPagination` class includes a number of `attributes` that may be overridden to modify the pagination style.

```
class ItemSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
     page_size = 1000
     page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
     max_page_size = 10000

pagination_class = ItemSetPagination
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `'MAX_PAGINATE_BY'` to configure the *global* maximum results per page, as the [doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination#pagination-in-the-generic-views) states.

Example from the [doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination#pagination-in-the-generic-views):

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'PAGINATE_BY': 10,                 # Default to 10
    'PAGINATE_BY_PARAM': 'page_size',  # Allow client to override, using `?page_size=xxx`.
    'MAX_PAGINATE_BY': 100             # Maximum limit allowed when using `?page_size=xxx`.
}
```

Set `max_paginate_by` to configure on a *per-view* basis for a hard maximum limit per page.

Example from the doc:

```
class PaginatedListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = ExampleModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExampleModelSerializer
    paginate_by = 10
    paginate_by_param = 'page_size'
    # Set MAX results per page
    max_paginate_by = 100
```